# Add a character in a string at certain location based on logic in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have comma separated data like this in one of the column

```
48FGTG,100ERTD,18NH,07EWR,9FDC,2POANAR,100GTEDC  
46FGTG,78ERTD,67NH,76EWR,3FDC
```

The numbers in the starting is percentage, whatever comes after the first alphabetic character is percentage, it varies from `0-100`.

I have to update the data like

```
48% FGTG,100% ERTD,18% NH,07% EWR,9% FDC,2% POANAR,100% GTEDC  
46% FGTG,78% ERTD,67% NH,76% EWR,3% FDC
```

I can filter out the percentile in regex, but not sure using it in SQL. Any lead would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like the design is the real problem, and the data should be in 2 columns multiple rows.

Comment: `I have comma separated data like this` don't use data like this. This violates the most basic design rule. Use a separate table to store those values, with separate columns for separate attributes. . You'll *have* to split that string into multiple rows to do what you want anyway. You're only wasting CPU time and storage space by storing strings like this

Comment: the data is from external source, the objecitve is to display the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like

```
select  STRING_AGG(substring(value,0,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',value))+'%'+substring(value,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',value),len(value)),',') from string_split('48FGTG,100ERTD,18NH,07EWR,9FDC,2POANAR,100GTEDC
46FGTG,78ERTD,67NH,76EWR,3FDC',',')
```

Here's what I have done

1.Use [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to find the first occurrence of character

2.Use [substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function to extract the first number and then remaining string

3.Use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to concatenates the values of string expressions and places separator values between them